# Do something when the player doesnt move for X time Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to make it when the player stands still for 5 seconds something happens but i cant get it to work
This is the code im using right now and it doesnt seem to be working
THis is C# and used for Unity

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

public float countdownTime = 5f; // The duration of the countdown timer
    private float timer; // The current countdown timer value


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //is for movement, it gets the x and z but not y as it is 0 because we dont jump in the game    
        Vector3 input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        //.normalized makes it so the player doesnt move faster diagonaly
        //Time.delta time make the player move the same speed no matter how good your computor is
        transform.position += input.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;


        Debug.Log(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
        Debug.Log(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));




        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Test Horizontal");
            if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") == 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Test Vertical");

                timer -= Time.deltaTime;
                Debug.Log(timer);
                if (timer <= 0f)
                {
                    // The countdown has finished, perform desired actions here
                    Debug.Log("Countdown finished!");
                    // Reset the timer or perform other actions as needed
                    timer = countdownTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Reset the timer if the player is moving
                    timer = countdownTime;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                timer = countdownTime;
            }
        }


    }      

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == ("Enemy"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
        }
    }

}
```

ive tryed using this

```
                timer -= Time.deltaTime;
```

but it doesnt seem to work the image shows what value the timer has it goes down a bit but goes back up it seems to be random

Comment: you dont appear to reset the movement if onluy hozizontal movement is done.  Otherwise it should do what you say so you need to debug it

Answer (score 0):

If timer has not reached zero, you're effectively resetting in back to `countdownTime` in the following `else` block.